# My ajax call is not giving any error and response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax call is not responding give me a empty result (PHP) code is properly working only issue i have is with ajax.
I'll already check all the CDN is working fine

My html code :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="<?= $id ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?= $_SESSION['id'] ?>">

    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating">
    <input type="submit" name="c_submit" id="c_submit">
</form>
<ol id="comment"> </ol>
```

My php code :

```
<?php
    include "../../functions/dbs.php";

    if (isset($_POST["c_submit"])){
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];     $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];           $rating = $_POST['rating'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO user_profile (product_id,user_id,comment,ratting) values ('$product_id','$user_id','$comment','$rating')";
        print_r($query);exit();
        $sql=mysqli_query($con->connect(),$query);
    ?>

    <li class="box">
        <?= '<span class="email">' . $product_id. '</span>' ?>
        <?= '<span class="comment">' . $comment . '</span>' ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

My ajax code :
If user can click on submit all the result that we have in input field will be shone in ol#comment.

```
$(function () {
    $("#c_submit").click(function() {
        var product_id = $("#product_id").val();    
        var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();          
        var rating = $("#rating").val();

        var dataString = 'product_id =' + product_id + '&user_id=' + user_id + '&comment=' + comment + '&rating=' + rating;
        if (product_id == '' || user_id == '' || comment == '' || rating ==''){
            alert('Please Give Valid Details');
        }else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "include/comm.php",
                data : dataString,
                cache: false,
                success : function(html){
                    console.log(html);
                    $("ol#comment").append(html);
                    $("ol#comment li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Ignore :

"The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex! Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz. Brick quiz "

Comment: check the developer tools console/network tab - you'll see that hitting a submit button will make a request - as you have no `action` attribute for the form, the request will be made to the current URL

Comment: There are 2 identical IDs in your page. **One** => `<textarea name="comment" id="comment"` And, **Second** => `<ol id="comment">
`. Which is wrong. ID can't be similar through out your page.

Comment: Handle `error` event of your Ajax and log the error to see what happened...

Comment: See @JaromandaX comment. You need to prevent submit default behaviour: `$("#c_submit").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });`

Comment: leave `print_r($query);exit();`

Comment: So there are several problems with your code as all we pointed...

Comment: And, from where `$email` is coming in this line `<?= '<span class="email">' . $email . '</span>' ?>` ??

Comment: Alex - Ajax don't post us on ( url : "include/comm.php" ) I was try your method before like i said we don't get any response

Comment: You're not using an `action` attribute in the form tag so your either add one or add your php code in the same php url of the form (and remove `exit()`)

Comment: @Alex OP wants to send request using ajax, so no need to set `action` attribute of `form`. But his server side code is wrong too. There are many problems in his posted code that need to be fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first prevent the default behavior of the click or submit event. You can do this by adding this line at the beginning of your event handler. Also, I never saw the way you called an anonym function using the `$` sign of jQuery object. I will assume that this function is the root or the wrapper function for your whole application and I will show you how I am doing it and how people do it.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('submit', '#info_form', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Add this line.

            var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
            var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
            var comment = $("#comment_input").val();
            var rating = $("#rating").val();

            var data = {
               product_id: product_id,
               user_id: user_id,
               comment: comment,
               rating: rating
            };

            if (product_id == '' || user_id == '' || comment == '' || rating == '') {
                alert('Please Give Valid Details');
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "include/common.php",
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        console.log(html);
                        $("ol#comment").append(html);
                        $("ol#comment li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

As per the way you are listening to the `submit` event. I think the way you are doing it now, will cause some problems if you start changing the HTML content or manipulating the DOM related to the form itself. I prefer to use
`$(document).on('submit', "#my-form-id", function(e){});` this way the listener will be bound to the document not to the element itself. I don't know if this is a bad practice or not but it solved lots of my issues in the past.
Also, I tend to wrap my event listeners code inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});` function to avoid executing the code before the DOM tree finish loading or the needed libraries that I am going to be using in my app.

For the data also, because you are using a post request to send your data. You have to preserve the structure of your data in the way you want to access them in the backend. In your front-end code, you are concatenating your parameters using string concatenation which is wrong. The `AJAX` function in jQuery take the data and serialize them. So in your case you have to do it like follow:

```
 var product_id = $("#product_id").val();    
 var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
 var comment = $("#comment").val();
 var rating = $("#rating").val();

 var data = {
   product_id: product_id,
   user_id: user_id,
   comment: comment,
   rating: rating
 };
```

And then pass it to the data parameter or field in the `ajax` function object.
You can find an example based on your solution [here](https://ajax-the-rigthway.herokuapp.com), and the code [here](https://github.com/mohessaid/ajax-the-right-way).

Comment: Ok, you can find the page here: https://ajax-the-rigthway.herokuapp.com and I will be updating the code here: https://github.com/mohessaid/ajax-the-right-way

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code snippet and found several problems with it:

1. Since you're using a , and you attach an event listener to the submit button and do not use preventDefault(), the button click will make the browser to send the form data without AJAX. I suggest you to use preventDefault() to prevent the synchronous process and use AJAX instead.
2. The PHP code relies on the c_submit POST data which does not exist in the formed data the javascript is submitting. So PHP will ignore the if() block entirely. This is why you do not see the expected result. I suggest you either update the if condition or just use other variable.
3. There is a typo in your javascript code, you included an excess whitespace in the dataString variable.
4. I concur with Alex's suggestion to attach the AJAX event to the form submit event instead of attaching to a button in the form. It is a form submit after all.

My code suggestion:

```
$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
        var dataString = 'product_id=' + product_id + '&user_id=' + user_id + '&comment=' + comment + '&rating=' + rating;
        ...
    });
});
```

For the PHP counterpart, assuming product_id data is always submitted, I suggest:

```
if (isset($_POST["product_id"])){
    ....
}
```

Comment: would be better to attach the event listener to the submit event of the form instead of the click of the submit button

Comment: I concur. It is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ol` id to `comment_answer` or anything else you want because you already have `comment` id on your `input`.

```
<ol id='comment_answer'></ol>
```

you need to prevent the default behavior of form submit, right now the page should be getting refreshed when you call on submit button which should not be done so, for that just write `return false;` after the ajax call, and change `ol#comment` to `ol#comment_answer` in ajax success function

```
$(function () {
    $("#c_submit").click(function() {
        var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
        var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var rating = $("#rating").val();

        var dataString = 'product_id =' + product_id + '&user_id=' + user_id + '&comment=' + comment + '&rating=' + rating;
        if (product_id == '' || user_id == '' || comment == '' || rating ==''){
            alert('Please Give Valid Details');
        }else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "include/comm.php",
                data : dataString,
                cache: false,
                success : function(html){
                    console.log(html);
                    $("ol#comment_answer").append(html);
                    $("ol#comment_answer li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                }

            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

***Changes***

**1)** IDs can't be same through out the page. a) `<textarea name="comment" id="comment"` & `<ol id="comment"></ol>`. 
Which is changed it to `<ol id="show_comment"></ol>`.

**2)** Since, no `action` is provided in the form and no `e.preventDefault();`, it will take current URL. For preventing it, add `e.preventDefault();` in the script.

**3)** In `include/comm.php` file, first condition you are checking `if (isset($_POST["c_submit"])){`. 
No `c_submit` attribute is passed in ajax script. So, it is not enetering in the condition. 
Pass `c_submit` in ajax script.

**4)** In `<?= '<span class="email">' . $email . '</span>' ?>` this line.

> Undefined Index `$email`

will come as no where `$email` is defined. So, check it. I've replaced it with `$user_id`

**Form**

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="<?= $id ?>" >
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?= $_SESSION['id'] ?>">
   <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating">
   <input type="submit" name="c_submit" id="c_submit">
</form>

<ol id="show_comment"></ol>
```

**include/comm.php**

```
<?php
include "../../functions/dbs.php";
if (isset($_POST["c_submit"])){
  $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  $rating = $_POST['rating'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO user_profile (product_id,user_id,comment,ratting) values ('$product_id','$user_id','$comment','$rating')";
  $sql= mysqli_query($con->connect(),$query);?>

  <li class="box">
    <?= '<span class="email">' . $user_id . '</span>' ?>
    <?= '<span class="comment">' . $comment . '</span>' ?>
  </li>
<?php }?>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#c_submit").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
    var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var rating = $("#rating").val();

    if (product_id === '' || user_id === '' || comment === '' || rating === ''){
      alert('Please Give Valid Details');
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "include/comm.php",
        data : {
          product_id : product_id, user_id : user_id, comment: comment, rating:rating,
          c_submit: true
        },
        cache: false,
        success : function(html){
          console.log(html);
          $("ol#show_comment").append(html);
          $("ol#show_comment li:last").fadeIn("slow");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

***Quick Links***

1. [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme)
2. [preventDefault() Event Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: Go through pending issues @Caster. It will help.

Comment: 3rd issue I found it long back. But, preparing answer for you took time to me. No problem. You try the answer given and if any problem comes. Feel free to ask @Caster.

Answer (score 0):

Until you don't echo the output in PHP, response will be blank.

Take the below code in a variable and echo the output:

```
$output = '<li class="box">
            '<span class="email">' . $email . '</span>'
            '<span class="comment">' . $comment . '</span>'
        </li>';
```

and echo the output : `echo $output`

Also in JS ajax content type should be `html/text` as you are sending html content in response.